# Como criar múltiplas entradas em um índice baseadas em colunas na mesma linha?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, otimização, índices

Eu nunca encontrei uma boa maneira de indexar várias colunas de uma linha como entradas de um índice ou simular esse recurso no MySQL.

O problema surge quando você tem campos funcionando como *tags* ou um conceito similar. Ex:. colunas com nomes `tag1`, `tag2`, `tag3`. Para procurar linhas com uma *tag* específica rapidamente requer que você tenha 3 índices e fazer 3 consultas separadas do jeito mais básico e óbvio.

Existe alguma maneira de indexar esses três campos como entradas de um único índice que permite realizar apenas uma busca.

Tentando exemplificar como ficaria

```
ID tag1 tag2 tag3
-- ---- ---- ----
01 abc  xyz  bla
02 foo  bar  ble
03 xyz  bla  bar

Como o índice se comportaria:

abc -> 01
bar -> 02 03
bla -> 01 03
ble -> 02
foo -> 02
xyz -> 01 03
```

Então se eu fizer uma busca por "bla", terei acesso aos IDs "01" e "03".

Há alguma outra maneira de fazer isso de forma eficientemente? Mesmo que mude a estrutura apresentada.

Comment: O objetivo é fazer uma consulta pela tag X e retornar os IDs com ela, ou uma consulta que retorne o "índice" inteiro? E você quer uma solução para essa estrutura específica de tabela, ou está aberto a rever a estrutura?

Comment: @bfavaretto editado para atender suas dúvidas

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Há algum tempo (2013? 2012?) desenvolvi um sistema muito semelhante ao da pergunta. Eu tinha alguns milhões de objetos e uma dúzia de "tags", e cada objeto poderia ter 0 ou mais tags associadas. Eu tinha que filtrar esses objetos baseados em buscas por conjuntos de tags. Semelhante, não?

Como o número de tags por objeto, no meu caso, era teoricamente ilimitado (visto que novas tags poderiam ser adicionadas ao sistema depois de lançado), a solução proposta na pergunta não me servia, i.e., eu não poderia utilizar uma tabela com colunas "tag1", "tag2", etc. Além disso, esse esquema não permite utilização de índices (veja meu primeiro comentário na resposta do @mgibsonbr).

Como eu necessitava de bastante performance (i.e., queries respondidas em "segundos"), na época fiz uma comparação entre diversas soluções, incluindo as duas propostas pelo @mgibsonbr em sua resposta.

A seguir, meus resultados -- se minha memória não falha!

### Trade offs...

A **solução "1." do @mgibsonbr** tem a desvantagem de possivelmente ocupar muito espaço em disco (já que você terá os "caracteres" das tags repetidos inúmeras vezes na tabela toda). Isso é uma desvantagem pois obriga o seu banco de dados a ter que ler muitas "pages" do seu disco rígido, então tem que girar muito o disco e mexer muito a cabeça de leitura, o que pode ter grande latência. A vantagem é que você faz apenas 1 select para obter o seu resultado.

Já a **solução "2." do @mgibsonbr** utiliza menos espaço em disco (pois na tabela gigante só serão salvos os ids das tags -- e se você utilizar o tipo numérico de tamanho adequado à quantidade máxima de tags, pode reduzir a 4, 2 ou até mesmo 1 byte por linha). Assim, você consegue ler mais linhas por "page" lido do disco reduzindo latência. Em contrapartida, o seu select provavelmente teria um join:

```sql
select from tags_objects, tags
 where tags.id = tags_objects.tagId
   and (tags.name = 'tag-buscado-1'
     or tags.name = 'tag-buscado-2') -- etc...
```

Esse join é o culpado por problemas de performance nessa solução.

### Solução mais eficiente (no meu caso de uso específico)

No final das contas, a solução mais eficiente que consegui foi utilizar a solução "2." com 2 selects distintos. O primeiro select busca os ids das tags, e o segundo select utiliza os ids das tags na tabela gigante. É como se eu fizesse o join "manualmente".

Isso era vantajoso para mim pois, no meu caso, era possível eu manter em cache, na minha aplicação, os ids dos tags. Esse cache era atualizado por um thread em background (fazendo um "full scan" na tabela minúscula que contém tags e seus ids a cada "X" segundos). No final das contas, em termos práticos, o cálculo "síncrono" era apenas um select na tabela gigante com a coluna "tagId" sendo algum tipo numérico, portanto menor do que ter que fazer joins.

Obviamente, por questões de performance, é necessário colocar um índice na coluna "tagId" da tabela gigante.

Antes de implementar toda essa solução, minhas queries duravam ~1min ou ~2min com, se não me engano, uns 5 tags. Após tudo isso, consegui reduzir o tempo das queries para algo em torno de ~10s!

### Considerações

É bastante complicado analisar de antemão qual será a solução com melhor performance nesse caso, pois realmente depende das características do seu projeto. Espero que esta resposta possa dar alguma orientação para a sua busca pela solução mais eficiente para o seu caso específico.

Comment: Excelente, ainda espero outras respostas mas tanto a sua quanto do mgibsonbr me ajudaram muito.

Answer (score 9):

Não posso falar da eficiência, mas uma maneira de se consultar por um valor usando uma única query seria utilizar o `IN` de uma maneira pouco convencional - com **as colunas** no lado direito. Exemplo:

```sql
select * from minha_tabela
where 'foo' in (tag1, tag2, tag3)
  and 'bar' in (tag1, tag2, tag3);
```

**Fonte:** o livro ["SQL Antipatterns"](http://it-ebooks.info/book/70/), em inglês.

P.S. Segundo esse mesmo livro, modelar os dados dessa maneira (Atributos Multi-Coluna) é uma má prática, e causa diversos problemas além desse da indexação (também complica a inserção, remoção, fazer com que cada tag só apareça no máximo uma vez por linha, etc). O ideal seria criar uma [tabela dependente](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.concepts.doc/concepts/ta_cncp_dependtab.htm) (ou uma [tabela de interseção/junção](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table), se cada tag for mais do que uma simples string) para associar as tags à tabela numa relação N para N. A menos que tenha suas razões para manter esse design, sugiro mudá-lo.

---

**Atualização:** como a pergunta foi editada de modo a admitir mudar a estrutura apresentada, vou complementar com exemplos de tabela dependente e tabela de interseção:

1. Tabela dependente

   ```sql
   PK                Índice  FK, Índice
   ID Etc            Tag     ID_Tabela
   -- ---            ---     ---------
   01                abc     01
   02                xyz     01
   03                bla     01
                     foo     02
                     bar     02
                     ...
   ```

   Nesse caso as tags foram movidas para uma tabela separada, onde cada tag está associada a apenas uma linha na tabela original. A coluna "tag" é indexada, de modo que a consulta `Tag -> IDs` seja rápida. E a coluna "id_tabela" - chave estrangeira para a tabela original - também é indexada, de modo que a consulta `ID -> Tags` tambem seja rápida.

   (Nota: a coluna "tag" não é `UNIQUE`, pois cada tag pode aparecer mais de uma vez na tabela.)
2. Tabela de interseção/junção

   ```
   PK                FK        FK              PK
   ID Etc            ID_Tabela ID_Tag          ID Tag
   -- ---            --------- ------          -- ---
   01                01        01              01 abc
   02                01        02              02 xyz
   03                03        02              03 bla
                     01        03              04 foo
                     03        03              05 bar
                     ...                       ...
   ```

   Nesse caso (útil caso você queira armazenar mais informações sobre uma tag, ou talvez em uma única query mudar o nome da tag sem mexer nas associações) as tags foram movidas para uma tabela separada, e uma tabela de interseção relaciona as duas (numa relação de N para N). Resta apenas adicionar índices onde for necessário, dependendo das consultas específicas que você pretende fazer.

Essas duas técnicas foram adaptadas também do livro, e em geral são boas práticas que também mantém seu modelo normalizado. Para questões de performance - as quais não posso opinar, pois nunca operei um sistema desse tipo **em escala** - onde se admite desnormalização ou outras técnicas de otimização (*caching*, [*offload* na camada de aplicação](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/60225/44542), etc) ver por exemplo [a resposta do @Bruno Reis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3010/215).

Comment: Resumiu bem o que eu ia dizer. Só acrescento que um índice composto nas 3 colunas seria utilizado numa query assim. Brinde: sqlfiddle que eu tinha pronto: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13f8a

Comment: @bfavaretto Se tem algo a acrescentar a respeito da eficiência, vá em frente, pois mesmo com o índice eu não saberia dizer se o meu SQL proposto é eficiente ou não.

Comment: @bfavaretto, por acaso o seu comentário se refere à resposta original, antes da primeira edição (i.e., ao `select ... where ... in`)? Se sim, um único índice composto nas 3 colunas na verdade não poderia ser utilizado. O motivo é simples. Suponha que o seu índice contém as colunas na ordem `(tag1, tag2, tag3)`. Agora suponha uma linha com `tag1 = xxx, tag2 = foo, tag3 = bar`. Nessa condição, a tabela inteira deve ser percorrida (i.e., full scan) para localizar essa linha, já que nada do `select` fixa tag1 = xxx.

Comment: @BrunoReis Exatamente! Eu entendo muito pouco de índices, por isso não quis fazer uma asserção, mas já desconfiava que meu código postado ia precisar de uma *full scan* - com ou sem índices...

Comment: @mgibsonbr, com relação a performance, é difícil dizer de antemão qual das soluções (i.e., 1-N ou N-N, que vc chamou "1." e "2." na edição) é mais eficiente. Há ~1 ano desenvolvi um sistema muito semelhante a isso no qual eu tinha alguns milhões de "objetos" e uma dúzia de tags (portanto, uns ~20M a ~30M de entradas numa tabela de relacionamento). A solução "1." gasta mais espaço em disco, então você provavelmente terá mais reads, o que pode ficar lento. Em contrapartida, "2." necessita join. [continua a seguir]

Comment: @mgibsonbr, [continuação] A solução mais eficiente que encontrei, no final, foi utilizar "2." porem com 2 selects distintos: no primeiro select, você obtem os ids dos tags que você busca. No segundo select, você filtra por "where tagId = XXX or tagId = YYY" etc para XXX, YYY, etc sendo cada um dos ids dos tags que vc encontrou no primeiro select! Com isso, consegui reduções da ordem de 90% no tempo de execução da query.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, por fim, se as tags não forem "criáveis" (i.e., diferente de como funciona o SO por exemplo em que se pode criar tags a qualquer momento), a solução mais eficiente, com certeza, é a solução "1." com as tags num campo do tipo "ENUM" -- já que, internamente, as linhas conterão apenas referências aos valores do ENUM no lugar de conter o "texto" das tags; isso evita reads excessivos pois reduz o tamanho da tabela e também evita a necessidade de fazer 2 selects!

Comment: @BrunoReis Cara, posta isso como uma resposta! A experiência prática de quem já passou por uma situação vale muito mais do que a opinião de quem só conhece a teoria...

Comment: @mgibsonbr, postado :-). Se quiser uma dica de leitura sobre índices, a documentação do MySQL é excelente. No MySQL 5.6, veja as seguintes páginas do manual: 8.3.1, 8.3.4, 8.3.5 e 8.8.3. Também pode ser útil estudar B-Trees em algum texto de estruturas de dados para entender mais a fundo os índices do MySQL (por exemplo em Algorithms, do Sedgewick).

Comment: @BrunoReis Sim, eu me referia à resposta original. Entendo a questão do índice, já que a condição não tem um AND dos valores das 3 colunas. Mas o EXPLAIN disse "using index", então estou confuso.

Comment: @bfavaretto, humm, curioso, de noite vou investigar mais a fundo!

Comment: @bfavaretto, como prometido, testei mais a fundo. Consegui criar uma situação em que o EXPLAIN realmente diz "using index", porém, na verdade, isso não significa que a query está sendo acelerada. Insira dezenas de milhares de linhas de forma que apenas uma pequena fração delas de match com a query. Depois rode o explain. Veja a coluna "rows", ela mostrará o número total de linhas da tabela -- a tabela toda deverá ser percorrida! Nesse caso, é praticamente indiferente para o MySQL usar o índice ou não, pois fará full scan da tabela ou do índice. [continua]

Comment: @bfavaretto [continuação]. Agora, aposto com você que, na query que vc rodou no explain, vc só pedia no result set os tags e, no máximo, a primary key. É justamente por isso que o MySQL *pode* usar o índice nesse caso: o índice contém todas as colunas que vc pede no result set (os 3 tags e mais a primary key). Agora, experimente pedir uma outra coluna, sei lá, um "nome", na sua query. Se vc não tiver essa coluna, adicione-a. Vc verá que, agora, através do EXPLAIN, que o MySQL nem mesmo pensa em usar o índice. Portanto, de fato, o índice não acelera em essa query pelos tags! Ficou claro o pq?

Comment: SQLFiddle com exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5a26/2

Mais info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html#jointype_index

Comment: Eu voltei lá no [meu sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d99c3/2), @BrunoReis, e você tem total razão. O *using index* some se você adiciona outra coluna no SELECT. E de fato ele faz o full scan. Ficou claro sim, obrigado pela explicação!

Comment: Bacana! Apenas um último detalhe: existe um motivo pelo qual, em casos extremos, pode realmente ser um pouco mais rápido executar a query pelo índice ao invés de executá-la pela tabela normal. O caso é se vc tiver muuuuitas colunas com muuuuitos dados. Full scan na tabela causará muitos reads no disco, o que é lento. Por outro lado, full scan no índice causará menos reads, pois o índice não contém as colunas "extras". Se no seu result set vc não pedir dados das outras colunas (exceto a primary key), então o select pelo índice é mais rápido por conta do menor tempo gasto lendo disco!

Answer (score 7):

[image: Query explicada]

No PostgreSQL se você criar um indice com multiplas colunas como o exemplo da figura e executar a query também como ilustrado ele será capaz de utilizar o indice para a consulta e tratará sozinho de resolver a consulta de modo eficiente ao executar um mapa de bits nos resultados parciais calculados.
Basta saber o motor de planejamento do MySQL irá tratar a execução da consulta da mesma maneira.

Comment: É exatamente como faço no PostgreSQL :)