# Dividir coluna em múltiplas tabelas

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Desejo salvar um conjunto de informações sobre filmes em um banco de dados mas tenho uma dúvida, devo organizar os gêneros em coluna (exemplo abaixo).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Banco de dados: MySQL 5.6.21

Engine: innoDB

ou organizar os gêneros em uma tabela a parte e utilizar uma terceira tabela para os relacionamentos?

utilizando a 1ª forma posso selecionar utilizando LIKE.

Comment: Porque o downvote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sugiro utilizar desta forma:

[image: Modelo Relacional]

Pois assim você poderá obter total controle dos filmes por gênero, quantos filmes de ação você possui, quantos filmes de ação e comédia você tem, utilizando apenas um `JOIN`.

Answer (score 7):

As duas formas são possíveis. O mais tradicional é usar uma tabela extra e normalizar o cadastro dos gêneros. Esta é a forma [normalizada](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados). Em geral você precisa ter um bom motivo para [não normalizar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22069/101).

Em qualquer das soluções, o ideal é ter uma tabela com as descrições dos gêneros. E aí você só usa o `ID` deles. Seja na coluna de `Generos` da sua tabela `Videos`, seja na tabela de amarração de filmes X gêneros - a forma mais recomendada.

Se ainda quiser manter uma lista de gêneros na coluna, pode ver uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3004/101) que eu fiz de como indexar isto.

Provavelmente você teria as tabelas:

#### Videos

```
Id
Titulo
Duracao
```

#### Generos

```
Id
Descricao
```

#### VideosXGeneros

```
Id
VideoId
GeneroId
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Esta forma simplifica e muito os sqls.